# Converting YBR_RCT Photometric Interpretation to RGB

Tags: python, pydicom, simpleitk, medical-imaging

I have a J2k Lossless dicom image and upon reading it with pydicom I see that it's in the YBR_RCT Color Space.

I want to convert the Color Space to RGB. I tried using the convert_color_space method from pydicom however, apparently this conversion is not implemented.

In their documentation they mention [this link](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.3.html#sect_C.7.6.3.1.2) as reference for their implementation of other conversions. That link also mentions some equations for converting from YBR_RCT to RGB.

I implemented the equations like so:

```
rgb_arr = np.zeros(orig_arr.shape).astype(np.float)
g = orig_arr[:,:,0] - np.floor((orig_arr[:,:,1]+orig_arr[:,:,2])/4)
r = g + orig_arr[:,:,2]
b = g + orig_arr[:,:,1]
rgb_arr[:,:,0] = r
rgb_arr[:,:,1] = g
rgb_arr[:,:,2] = b
rgb_arr = np.clip(rgb_arr,0,255).astype(orig_arr.dtype)
```

However, after this when I visualize the image through plt.imshow(), I see that it's very purplish.
I doubt what I have done is right and I haven't really found another package that does this conversion.

I have tried using SimpleITK, however its not clear to me if it does the color space conversion or not.

Please let me know if you know how to do this conversion.

Comment: The `np.clip()` step is a bit suspicious, are you sure you have unsigned 8-bit pixel data?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell without a dataset to play with, but given RCT is intended to be losslessly reversible, the following should be sufficient (no clipping needed):

```py
from pydicom import dcmread
import numpy as np

ds = dcmread("path/to/file")
arr = ds.pixel_array

rgb = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
rgb[..., 1] = arr[..., 0] - np.floor((arr[..., 1] + arr[..., 2]) / 4)
rgb[..., 0] = arr[..., 2] + rgb[..., 1]
rgb[..., 2] = arr[..., 1] + rgb[..., 1]
```

But when using *pydicom* this step shouldn't be necessary as the various pixel data handlers all perform the RCT to RGB conversion implicitly when decoding.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
Using the formula from [the link](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.3.html#sect_C.7.6.3.1.2) yield strange colored pictures
I don't know why but if I treat the YBR_RCT Photometric Interpretation files as RGB, it will result in acceptable colors (less bright though...)

for example:
load dicom file as 'RGB'

```
ds = pydicom.dcmread(file_path, force=True)
pixel_array = ds.pixel_array.astype(float)
```

to display by pillow, simply

```
from PIL import Image
display(Image.fromarray(np.uint8(pixel_array)))
```

to save image by opencv, we have to convert pixel_array to BGR

```
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('E:\\test.jpg', cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(pixel_array), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using SimpleITK. It is built on top of GDCM. GDCM will make sure to decompress JPEG 2000 codestream / YBR_RCT into proper decompressed buffer in RGB space.

Please note that this is mandated by the DICOM standard:

- http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.html

> If Pixel Data (7FE0,0010) is sent in a Native Format, then the
> Photometric Interpretation (0028,0004) shall be other than:
>
> YBR_RCT

Comment: Well no, the quoted section just means that *uncompressed* Pixel Data stored/sent in a dataset shouldn't use YBR_RCT. It's definitely not mandated by DICOM that the decompression process result in RGB data.

Comment: @scaramallion Could you please specify the value of Photometric Interpretation for an input DICOM J2K with YBR_RCT being decompressed ?

Comment: I meant that (as I understand it) the colour transforms performed by the various JPEG libraries prior to compression or after decompression are just features of the libraries themselves, not a requirement of the JPEG standard. But now that I think about it, I'm not sure if that's true for J2K. If you were decompressing YBR_RCT and it wasn't in RGB colour space you'd definitely convert it and use RGB as the *Photometric Interpretation*.

Comment: Looking at G.1.2 in 15444-1 it says "[Inverse DC level shifting] is performed after [the] computation of the inverse multiple component transformation (RCT or ICT)", so I guess for J2K at least the conversion on decompression is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util as util

ds = pydicom.dcmread(file_path, force=True)

pixel_array = ds.pixel_array 

# If pixel_array is image, then it'll work. 
# If pixel_array is video, then do this for individual frames of the video

rgb_pixel_array = util.convert_color_space(pixel_array,'YBR_FULL','RGB')

cv2.imwrite("rgb_dicom.jpg", rgb_pixel_array)
```